# Question about a proof in Washington's book "Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields" of the ramification in $\mathbb {Z}_p$-extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to understand the Proposition : "$\mathbb{Z}_{p}$-extension are unramified outside $p$"  as formulated in Chapter 13  section 13 .1  of Washington's book "***Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields***".

Let $K_{\infty}/K$ be a $\mathbb {Z}_p$-extension and let $\frak L$ be a prime (possibly 
archimedean) of $K$ which  lie above $l \neq p.$ And let $I\subset \mathrm{Gal}(K_{\infty}/K)\cong \mathbb {Z}_p$  be the inertia group for $\frak L.$ Since $I$ is closed  , $I=0$ or $I=p^n\mathbb {Z}_p$ for some $n$ assume that $I\neq 0.$ In particular, $I$ is infinite, then we may assume that $\frak L$ is non-archimedean (because $I$ must have order 1 or 2 for infinite primes). For each $n,$ choose inductively a place $\frak{L}_n$ of $K_{n}$ lying above $\frak {L}_{n-1}$   with $\frak{L}_0= \frak{L},$ Let $\overline {K}_{n}$ be the completion of $K_n$ at $\frak {L}_n$, and let $\overline {K}_{\infty}=\bigcup \overline {K}_n.$

Question 1: why we may assume that : $I\subset \mathrm{Gal}(\overline {K}_{\infty}/\overline {K}).$

Question 2: how to proof  that :$ U\cong (\mbox{finit group})\times \mathbb{Z}_{l}^{a}$

where  $U$ be the units of $\overline {K}$ and $a\in \mathbb Z.$

thank you in advance

Comment: The second result is just standard theory of local fields. Exponention describes U^1 as a cyclic group times a free Z_l module. Then U is a finite group of roots of unity times U^1.  This is in Falko Lorenz's book on local fields . I'm sure it's in Serre too.

Comment: @AlexYoucis thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. Where did you assume that $I\subseteq\text{Gal}(\overline{K}_\infty/\overline{K})$?

Comment: @AlexYoucis in the proof  the assumption  $I\subset \mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K}_{\infty}/\overline{K})$ unjustified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1 is a statement about Galois groups of completions. The Galois group of $\bar{K}_\infty/\bar{K}$ is isomorphic to the decomposition group of $l$ in $\operatorname{Gal}(K_\infty/K)$, and the inertia group is a subgroup of the decomposition group.

For question 2, Washington actually gives a proof right after stating the fact.(It's essentially the same as the argument Alex Youcis has sketched in the comments). The logarithm used in this proof is defined in section 5.1. What part of that proof are you having trouble with?

Comment: thank you brett, but $Gal(\overline{K}_{\infty}/\overline{K})\cong$ decomposition group of $\frak L$ in the case where $[K_{\infty}:K]$ is finite ???

Comment: @Amine It's certainly true for all finite extensions. Now take projective limits to get the statement for infinite extensions, using the fact that if $L/K/F$ is an abelian tower of fields, the decomposition group of $L/F$ surjects onto $K/F$ under the restriction homomorphism.

Comment: for Question 2 in Washington's he defined ouver $log_{l}$ ouver $U$ but in  Falko Lorenz's book defined ouver $U^{(1)}!$

Comment: thank you for the indication, you have a reference that treats the infinite case ?

Comment: @Amine I'm not familiar with Lorenz's book so I could be misinterpreting his notation, but $U^{(1)}$ generally (for example, in Serre) means the group of units whose residue class is $1$. Washington calls this group $U_1$. So $U\cong k^* \times U^{(1)}$.

Comment: @Amine I don't have a reference (probably somewhere in Serre), but I've already sketched the proof for you. Once you parse what I've written using the definition of projective limits, decomposition, and inertia groups, it should be pretty immediate.

Comment: thank you sir for your help :)